# Rare exception in .net with Twitterizer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, twitterizer

When I debug and/or run it on my develop machine it works great, but when I deploy it to a Win2008, I get the following error, any idea?

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12633595
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +224
   Twitterizer.TwitterizerException.ParseRateLimitHeaders(WebResponse response) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\Exceptions\TwitterizerException.cs:205
   Twitterizer.TwitterizerException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\Exceptions\TwitterizerException.cs:100
   Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callbackAddress) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\OAuth\OAuthUtility.cs:95
   PPRR.Controllers.TwitterrController.LogOn(String returnUrl, Nullable`1 perm) in C:\Users\ranu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PPRR\PPRR\Controllers\TwitterrController.cs:37
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +172
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in Twitterizer, triggered by an auth issue in your config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your application registration is incorrect. Go to http://dev.twitter.com and view your application. There you will see that the application is registered as a desktop application. In order to be a web application, you must specify a callback address. I suggest you provide your sites homepage, since you will provide the 'real' callback address at runtime.

The error message you are seeing is a bug and should be addressed in the next release.